# Sencha Touch 2: launch() function doesn't fire

Tags: function, extjs, controller, sencha-touch-2, launch

Can anybody explain me why this function

launch: function(){ console.log('launch'); },

doesn't display `'launch'` word in the console?
There are no errors in the console.

Seems like I use it in a proper place in a proper Controller.

I want to use this function to pass values to the view.

All the rest (including other controller functions) works fine.

Why doesn't it get fired?

Comment: did you include your Controller in the Ext.app.Application list of controllers?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, I did.

Comment: can you show us your app.js code? What do you see on browser?

Answer (score 0):

The Ext.app.Controller's launch function is improperly documented as a config rather than as a method.  I'm not sure if this is the issue you had, but it tricked me.

So, instead of:

```
Ext.define('MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        launch: function() { console.log('launch'); }
    }
}
```

It should be:

```
Ext.define('MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    launch: function() { console.log('launch'); }        
}
```